# Youtube API loop stops

Tags: javascript, loops, youtube-data-api

I'm very new to programming.
I'm trying to make a project where a locally hosted website, would fetch titles of the songs from a youtube playlist and then adds them to a list.
So far, it fetches the first 50 items/titles, but then the loop stops.
What goes wrong here?

```
let tracks = [];
let token = "";
let items;
let items_total;

function execute() {
        do {
        return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            "part": ["snippet"],
            "maxResults": 50,
            "pageToken": token,
            "playlistId": "id of the playlist"
        }).then(function(response) {
            let playlist = response;

            items = playlist.result.pageInfo.resultsPerPage;
            items_total = playlist.result.pageInfo.totalResults;
            token = playlist.result.nextPageToken;

            for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {tracks.push(playlist.result.items[i].snippet.title)}
        },
        function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
    } while (tracks.length < items_total)
}
```

Comment: You are sending a parameter that limits how many results your request will have: ```"maxResults": 50,```

Comment: You have a return statement in your while loop, as soon as that line is executed it is going to return none of the other iterations are going to happen

Comment: W/o the maxResults 50, the default value will be 5.
Removing the return statement didnt help either.

Comment: `while (tracks.length < items_total)` your `tracks` variable is an empty array, that condition is going to be false since it is going to be reached before your api request is going to finish processing. Loop structures like `while` are not async aware, meaning they are not going to wait till some async function finishes before moving on.

Comment: Tried the function with async, this fixed the problem.
Thank you!